# How can I get Device Unique Id for windows phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, unique-id

I want Unique Device Id for back_end service (ws) for that I found following reference

```
  private string GetDeviceId()
    {
        var token = Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
        var hardwareId = token.Id;
        var dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(hardwareId);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[hardwareId.Length];
        dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);

        return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "");
    }//Note: This function may throw an exception.
```

but, I can't understand the code , every time I get same Id for my Device (64 character string ), I want to know that it is applicable or not ?
I couldn't found any reference from MSDN also

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This may help:

```
private string GetDeviceID()
{
    HardwareToken token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
    IBuffer hardwareId = token.Id;

    HashAlgorithmProvider hasher = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Md5);
    IBuffer hashed = hasher.HashData(hardwareId);

    string hashedString = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(hashed);
    return hashedString;
}
```

For the documentation, have a look at the [GetPackageSpecificToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification.getpackagespecifictoken.aspx)  method in the [HardwareIdentification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification.aspx) class.

Comment: Instead of the hardcoded *"MD5"*  you can use `HashAlgorithmNames.Md5`

Comment: @KristianVukusic Thank you. I have updated my answer.

Comment: This PackageSpecificToken is changed once you change hardware profile (unplug BT or something else). I'd not rely on it. Maybe only for ad purposes.

Comment: Anyway if you use it you should handle its "drift": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396